# typeahead.js does not get data from local

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, typeahead.js, bloodhound

First of all, it's a newbie question :) Sorry for bothering you...

I've managed to get data from Firebase Firestore, and put that data in a variable.

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
  let contentJSON = [];
db.collection("blog-posts").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
var listTemp = {
    "category": doc.data().category,
    "content": doc.data().content,
    "date": doc.data().date,
    "slug": doc.data().slug,
    "title": doc.data().title
  };
contentJSON.push(listTemp)
    });
});
```

Then I create the new Bloodhund instance with this local data.

```
var blogPosts = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('content'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: contentJSON,
  });
```

Nothing appears when I search through this setup.
I've tried to run it with external JSON with the Prefetch method and it worked, however, I need to run it with local data. I think there is a problem with the structure of the local data variable. Could you please take a look and help me?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably an AJAX problem that could be solved with promises and async/await.

The first body of code must resolve `.then()` you may run the second body of code. Otherwise the firebase code completes *after* the bloodhound, and it must complete before.

If you put the firebase code into a function like this

```
// (1) add async here
async getBlogPosts() {
  var db = firebase.firestore();
  // (2) add return here
  return db.collection("blog-posts").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    // (3) move variable in here
    let contentJSON = [];
    var listTemp = {
    "category": doc.data().category,
    "content": doc.data().content,
    "date": doc.data().date,
    "slug": doc.data().slug,
    "title": doc.data().title
    };
    contentJSON.push(listTemp)
    // (4) return here
    return contentJSON
    });
});
```

And then call it with an await in your front end code

```
// (5) the async await will make sure this function happens before we proceed
var contentJSON = await getBlogPosts()
var blogPosts = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('content'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: contentJSON,
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It says there is an error in the code.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier(First })

Comment: can you post the full error? did you include firestore package in your app ?